# How to map two child objects to each other in Python

Tags: python, oop

Tough for me to find a good title for this problem. Please refer to code.

```
class School:
     def __init__(self, info):
         self.name = info['name']
         self.student = info['students']
         for x in self.student:
             self.child[self.student[0]] = Child(x, self.student[x])
             self.student[x] = Student(x, self.student[x])

class Student:
     def __init__(self, student_info, student_id):
         self.id = student_id
         self.name = student_info[0]
         self.age = student_info[1] 
         self.sex = student_info[2] 
         self.attendance = False 

class Child(Student)
     def __init__(self, student_info, student_id):
         self.id = student_info[0]
         self.student_id = student_id        

schools = {1:{'name':'Hard Knocks', 'students':{1:['Tim',12,M], 2:['Kim',11,M]}}}
```

Pretty much I want to be able access the Student parameter 'attendance' using both the Student and Child object within the School instance.

```
#instantiating
for x in students:
    schools[x] = School(schools[x])

schools[1].student[1].attendance = True
print schools[1].child['Tim'].attendance
```

I want the last line to print True since I set schools[1].student[1].attendance, but its printing False. How do I map it so when i set the child['Tim'] object, its the same as setting the student[1] object. student[1] and child['Tim'] should be mapped to the same Student object's parameter.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `Student` constructor from the `Child` one to initialized its attributes. You can do this with `super` (a requirement in multiple inheritance scenarios) or use the `Student` class explicitly.

Example using super:

```
class Child(Student)
  def __init__(self, student_info, student_id):
    super().__init__(student_info, student_id)
    ...
```

Probably you also want to remove the duplicated `id` attribute from the    `Child` class.

For more info on super: [Understanding Python super() with __init__() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)

Comment: Also, on the class hierarchy from the question, you could instantiate just one `child` object and refer to it from both child and student arrays, as every  `Child` object is also a `Student` one.

Comment: super().__init__(student_info, student_id) raises 'TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)'

Comment: I tried super(Child,self).__init__(student_info, student_id) and Student(object), using super doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, the `super()` (no args) is a Python 3 feature. In Python 2 you need to use the second form (with the explicit class) but the class you put in super is the class where you call the super, in this case, `Child`, not the parent one. Think of it something like "I need the super class of Child"